# Taking elements in decreasing order from an array in shared memory

Tags: c, arrays, linux

I have a program with two types of processes: A and B. All B processes need to read an array in shared memory containing information about every A. Then, B-type process needs to contact an A with the highest score. A can accept or reject the message, if it accepts, both processes die. If A rejects, then B should find the second highest and try again, and so on. I can only think about this solution :

```
while(running) {

    pList* iterator = sharedStructure;

    int highestPid;
    int highestScore = -1;

    while(iterator->pid) {  // If entry exists
        if(!inContacted(iterator->pid)) { // If A process was not contacted before
            if(iterator->score > highestScore) {
                highestScore = iterator->score;
                highestPid = iterator->pid;
            }
        }
        iterator++;
    }

    // Contact highestPid 

    if(accepted) {
        // exit
    } else {
        addToContacted(highestPid);
    }
}
```

Also, contacted array needs to be emptied after a B tried to contact everyone, so it can start over. This solution seems bad to me, what could be a better one?

Note: In complete code there are semaphores that control access to shared memory.

Comment: "_B-type process needs to contact an A with the highest score._" So if an A and B died, an A that had rejected earlier could now be an A with the highest score. I don't see you do that.

Comment: So I sugest: `if(accepted) { clearContacted(highestPid); exit;}` to clear the list and remove A, which now no longer exists.

Comment: A better way would be to sort the array (if the A's have exclusive access), then work from the top. Remove contacted As by moving the array down and adjusting a variable `n_inuse` or alike that tracks the number of elements in use of the array. If it reaches zero, the array is empty.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie, I simplified the problem, in reality it's not the highest score, but the highest GCD between B's "score" and score of A. So I can't sort array in shared memory, because every B has its own order. Also A deletes its entry from shared array before exit. Sorry for not being clear enough, and thank you very much for answering.

Comment: What are the criteria for A to accept or reject?

Comment: "what could be a better solution" cannot be answered from the information in your question because it is incomplete. Also, in no way does your code match the revised specification. The "right" combination of data structure and algorithm can only be found/designed when all information is available. In your GCD addition you can create an NxN matrix with the GCDs of each combination (and set members used to zero).

Comment: @PaulOgilvie B sends GCD to A, if GCD is one of n highest possible for A (A has an array with all its factors), then A accepts. If A rejects 10 times, n is incremented by 1.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie by "better solution" I meant to ask for a way to iterate an shared array, which is constantly updated, picking always the best possible match (highest GCD with A that did not previously reject B). Again, sorry if I'm not being clear, but the complete code is too long to include/explain.

Comment: @Sepfins: Are the properties of A processes static (except when completely removed following an accept, of course), or do they dynamically change?

Comment: @NominalAnimal they are static

Comment: No, this approach makes no sense to me. The solution obtained this way is not guaranteed to be *"best"* in any sense of the word. In fact, it is reminescent of the traveling salesman problem (with an additional constraint that there are many salesmen and more important cities need to be serviced first), except that you haven't even specified how the pool A processes are ordered amongst themselves. In short, this problem is woefully underspecified, and any implementation/solution will be basically random: not useful in any way I can perceive.

Comment: @NominalAnimal, I just described my problem in a very bad way, I guess. I'll try to do an example just for clarity and close the question. After all this method works, and I'll stick with it. So, example: 
Shared A's score array (in complete code it's a struct with a score variable): [ 78, 20, 65];
B1's score: 10;
B2's score: 13;
B1 should communicate As in this order: [A[1], A[2], A[0]] ('cause highest GCD of 10 is with 20, second highest with 65...);
B2's order should be: [A[0], A[2], A[1]].

Comment: As you have a running code, you could ask for a full review at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Read their help center first because their rules are not exactly the same as SO ones. The good point is that longer code would be acceptable there.

Comment: @Sepfins: Let's say A[1] and A[0] reject the bids in the same real time, and B1 and B2 bid A[2] at the same time. **What should happen?** You say you require the *"best"* solution, but no rules as to how to solve these races. Or, what if B2 is faster than B1, and gets rejected by A[0], A[2], and A[1]: what happens then? It has been completely rejected. These are not just details, these are the rules that need to be defined, when you wish to find the optimum solution (across all processes, over both pools).

Comment: @NominalAnimal as written in the note, there are semaphores that control the races. Only one B can read shared structure/bid/receive reply at a time, another B will be able to do that only when first B got its reply.